# Is there a way to force relationships to load in a particular order in a Lumen/Laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a Lumen (8) model with a relationship that is dependent on another relationship. I want to be able to do the following,

```
    public function getThingId(): int
    {
        return $this->thing->id;
    }

    public function thing(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Thing::class);
    }

    public function otherThing(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OtherThing::class, 'another_id')->where('thing_id', '=', $this->getThingId())->where(/* some more criteria */);
    }
```

This does not work. `$this->getThingId()` returns `null` in the `otherThings` relationship. If I use `$this->thing->id` everything works. I would prefer, however, to use `$this->getThingId()`.

Is there a way to force Laravel to load the `thing` relationship prior to the `otherThing` relationship? (or maybe there is something else going that I'm not picking up on).

Comment: Maybe `OtherThing` should be a relationship of `Thing`, not... Whatever this class is (I'm going to call it `FirstClass`). Then you can do `FirstClass::with('thing.otherThing')->get()`. Unless `another_id` plays into this, but when you use pseudo-classes, it get's a little hard to help. If you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77827650/edit) to include the actual Classes and their related database columns, we can probably provide better help.

Comment: I agree with @TimLewis, maybe with the real classes will help us. You tried to put `with` relationship in `otherThing()`?   `$this->hasMany(OtherThing::class, 'another_id')->with('thing')->...`

Comment: are you trying to eager load? how is `otherThing` relationship being accessed in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the eager loading of the thing relationship before accessing `getThingId()` by using the `load` method. Here's how you can modify your `otherThing` relationship to ensure that the thing relationship is loaded:

```
public function otherThing(): HasMany
{
    $this->load('thing'); // Eager load the 'thing' relationship

    return $this->hasMany(OtherThing::class, 'another_id')->where('thing_id', '=', $this->getThingId())->where(/* some more criteria */);
}
```